# DDWRT/iptables - block outgoing connections on ALL ports except 80 and 443

Tags: iptables, router

A bit lost with ddwrt here... It's actually straight-up iptables but I can't figure it out. All I need to do is:

1. Block ALL outgoing connections on ALL ports, except 80 and 443.
2. Block ALL incoming connections -- nobody should be able to connect in.

Any help, links, or clues would be most appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you ask for, I assume you can connect via serial, or you will be effectively locking yourself out. Nobody can make incoming connections, not even you. I have set the `FORWARD` chain to `DROP`, change that to match your needs.

```
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s $ip -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22,80,443 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -j DROP
COMMIT
```

Replace `$ip` with the source IP you will be connecting from.
Of course, if you are working with zones, the configuration is totally different.

Comment: First of all, thank you! Second, is there a way to do this without locking myself out? Allow connection to the admin panel from a specific IP within the local subnet (192.168.0.16, say)?

Comment: @ezuk I have added an `INPUT` rule to allow incoming traffic from a configurable source IP.

Comment: Not that much, there were two important rules missing, please check the last edition to the answer

Comment: And you probably want your router to `FORWARD` traffic